# Ajax increment seq

Tags: ajax

I think this is the last issue that I have on my dev site before going live.

In `index.twig` I'm outputting the latest articles, some of them are duplicated.

In the footer I'm having `popper.js` tooltip where on click of a “LIKE” button I can update the tooltip to have information about `entry.id`

Now I have to do `seq(‘likes’ next=true)` on that entry via AJAX and that's where I need help.

I can't do this via Sprig because it's the whole homepage.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

If I understand correctly, Sprig is still an option, so long as you can localize the trigger + swap behavior. Try this out!

In your homepage template, add the like button, targeting a custom route/path that includes a query param with the current post’s ID:

```
{% set featured = craft.entries()
  .section('blog')
  .featured(true)
  .all() %}

<ul>
  {% for post in featured %}
    <li>
      {{ post.title }}
      <button
        class="like like--inactive"
        s-trigger="click"
        s-get="{{ url('ajax/like', { postId: post.id }) }}"
        s-swap="outerHTML">Like</button>
    </li>
  {% endfor %}
</ul>
```

Then, in a new template located at `templates/ajax/like.twig`, add this:

```
{% set target = craft.entries()
  .section('posts')
  .id(craft.app.request.getRequiredQueryParam('postId'))
  .one() %}

{# Bail if the user provided a bogus ID: #}
{% if not target %}
  {% exit 404 %}
{% endif %}

{# Increment the post’s “like” sequence (this key isn’t important—it just needs to be unique to each post): #}
{% set likes = seq("post-#{target.id}:likes") %}

<div class="like like--active">
  Liked {{ likes }} time(s)
</div>
```

There isn't anything particularly special about this—it's just a template that renders an HTML fragment, and is only intended to be swapped out via Sprig. Its context (the post entry) is loaded dynamically based on the incoming `postId` query parameter.